# What scope to you use for class with producer methods in CDI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

Let's say I have a class which just produces some beans, lists, items and so on like

```
public class MightyProducer {

    @Produces
    public Bean1 someBean() {
         //some init
         return new Bean1();
    }

    @Produces
    @CoolItems
    public List<Items> items() {
        //some init
        return new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

}
```

What should be a scope for class like this?Should I leave it to `@Dependent` or is there any best practice?I've read somewhere that `CDI` Singleton is good for this but I really don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of the class containing the producer really shouldn't matter a whole lot, however, the scope of the item being produced matters. If there isn't a scope annotation on the producer field / method then it will produce that object at the scope of the containing class.

Comment: So there is no difference between marking a producer class let's say as a `@Singleton` or a `@RequestScoped`?

Comment: In CDI `@Singleton` effectively becomes the same as `@ApplicationScoped`. If you aren't specifying a scope for the things you're producing and the bean containing the producer(s) is `@RequestScoped` then the produced beans will also be `@RequestScoped`.

Answer (score 11):

This thread was the only one I could find on this subject. Since I didn't find the answers completely satisfactory, I ran a little experiment where I once declared the class containing a `@Produces` method with an `@ApplicationScoped` annotation and once without it. I traced the construction of instances of my producer class in a private constructor.

I found that in the case where the producer class IS annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`, only a single instance is ever created, which is fairly obvious. But without the annotation, a new instance is created whenever the `@Produces` method is called due to an instance of a bean that has the produced type injected being created.

So there might be a little point in making the producer class `@ApplicationScoped` to reduce (needless) object creation. But since object creation is supposedly so cheap nowadays, that's probably only relevant if the producer class has at least some state to be initialized.

Comment: This answer pretty much matches the documentation at https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/producermethods.html#d0e3306

Answer (score 0):

Since this class is stateless (does not store values in member variables) and does not depend on scoped instances, you can safely use a singleton.